# Checking a triplet is triangular or not?

Tags: java

This solution of mine has 1 test failed.
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingU5HYHS-MDC/

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
             if(A.length<3)
            return 0;

       Arrays.sort(A);

       for(int i=0;i<A.length-2;i=i+1)
       {
           if(  A[i]+A[i+1]>A[i+2]  )
           {
               return 1;
           }

       }

       return 0;
    }
}
```

but this solution has passed 100% percent, but i cant understand why
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingYKT8FB-TAV/

```
class Solution {
    /**
     * Check whether there is a triangular
     * @param A         The array for length of lines
     * @return          0: no triangular found
     *                  1: triangular is found
     */
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // Handle with the special cases
        if(null == A || A.length < 3) return 0;

        // Sort the input, and then try to find the triangular
        Arrays.sort(A);
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length-2; i++) {
            // Beware of overflow
            if (A[i] >= 0 && A[i] > A[i+2] - A[i+1]) {
                return 1;
            }
            /*
             * We already know A[i+1] <= A[i+2]. If A[i] < 0,
             * A[i] + A[i+1] < A[i+2]
             */
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the failing test case and debug both solutions to see the difference.

Comment: @luk2302 it doesn't show details of failing test cases. it just says extreme_arith_overflow1 
overflow test, 3 MAXINTs

Comment: yes, what do you think 3 MAXINTs might refer to?

Comment: @luk2302 dunno. issue is in the if condition in the for loop. iv tried if(  A[i] >= 0 && A[i]+A[i+1]>A[i+2]  ) which is also not 100% percent which is strange

Comment: https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingX7GZKJ-U98/

Comment: Hint: What is MAXINT + MAXINT?

Comment: A consisting of N integers . N is an integer within the range [0..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code fails when using 2 values that together are > than the maximum value an integer can be assigned to.

In the line `if(  A[i]+A[i+1]>A[i+2]  )` you are making an addition. If this exceeds the integer limit you will run into an integer overflow.

The other code avoids this by never doing such an addition.

Comment: "you will run into undefined behavior" - that is not technically true, it is defined behaviour, unexpected but well defined.

Comment: thanks for help; i fixed it by (long) A[i]+A[i+1]> (long) A[i+2]

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out luk2302. I changed it to simply say 'integer overflow' which should be more precise.

Answer (score 4):

**Inequality rule:**
which states: the length of a side of a triangle is less than the sum of the lengths of the other two sides and greater than the difference of the lengths of the other two sides.

If we go through the sides `a + b > c`

if the sum of `A[I] + A[I+1]` larger than the capacity of `int` then it becomes a case of `overflow`, and the result of `A[I] + A[I+1] < 0` => `A[I] + A[I+1] not greater than A[I+2]`.

Here `if(  A[i]+A[i+1]>A[i+2]  )` returns `false` when overflow occurs.

So, better to use,

```
if (A[i + 2] >= 0 && A[i + 2] > A[i + 1] - A[i])

or 

if (A[i] >= 0 && A[i] > A[i+2] - A[i+1])
```